# Does Ubiquity support installing via PXE?

Tags: 10.10, ubiquity, pxe

I have a PXE server at home for doing [network-based installs](http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/netboot/), which uses the text-based alternate installer.

However in 10.10 the Ubiquity (aka graphical) installer has some really nice features; like installing in the background while I fill out my user information, installing updates as part of the install, and it looks pretty great.

Is there a way to set up netboot with ubiquity so I can use my existing PXE server but have a nice graphical installation?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to export the live filesystem over NFS, and set the NETBOOT and NFSROOT kernel command line parameters.

See [this help document](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/LocalNet) (under "A variation") for the full details.

Answer (score 3):

The trick is to load a minimal system with NFS-Support. This system can start the graphical installer. [This hotwo](http://www.digitalpeer.com/id/linuxnfs) should help setting this up.

If you like experimenting around with pxe I recommend [fog](http://www.fogproject.org/), this has alot of features and will setup part of the installation by itself. It will also allow you to backup partitions over network and load them back.

Comment: Thanks for the pointer to fog. I wasn't aware of that before, but I'm excited to try it out.

Comment: I accepted evan's answer since it linked me to official docs, but +1 for the other information!