# How do I setup a server remotely?

Tags: 10.10, server, installation, setup, remote-access

I can run (and have run) the install fine with a monitor attached the machine, but what I wish to do is setup Ubuntu server remotely (within my home network).

I have a USB drive pre-loaded and ready to go. Where do I go from here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You might want to have a look at the answer I gave here:

[Clean Install Of Ubuntu Server over the network?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/8539/clean-install-of-ubuntu-server-over-the-network)