# How to install Ubuntu without a CD and a USB?

Tags: installation

I want to install Ubuntu WITHOUT using either of the following:

- CD
- USB

Comment: @tijybba Actually, [you can](http://askubuntu.com/questions/8539/clean-install-of-ubuntu-server-over-the-network#8559), but until we get more information from the OP we won't know if that's a reasonable solution here.

Comment: That's a great question. All I use the CD drive for is installing OSes, some times I also use a USB flash drive which is slow as hell. And today it has just hit me: why can't I use a special hard drive partition the same way like I use the CD or USB drive - just "burn" the ISO on that partition and boot from it? I think it would be much faster, needles to say more convenient. That's a huge pity there is no good answer here so far...

Answer (score 6):

Ways to install without CD or USB:

1. Got net? With a network connection and another machine, you can network boot to an installer.
2. Install on a hard drive in a machine that DOES have CD or USB and then move the hard drive to the lacking machine.
3. Floppy! (just kidding).
4. Other mass storage interfaces For example Firewire, eSATA etc.