# How can I boot a live system from a hard disk and then install to the same drive?

Tags: installation, boot, hard-drive, live-cd, floppy

I need to install Lubuntu on to a hard drive that has no other means of installation other than the hard drive itself (USB, CD, Net, none of those are available on this system).

What I have already tried: I installed a LiveCD onto the HDD and it runs fine, but when I try to install to the same drive, no matter on which partition I choose (tried root, boot, and swap partition, using free space, etc.) it errors out. The errors I get are mostly about not being able to unmount the drive to install, or it being in use. This was tried on several HDD's so it isn't the drive.

Specifics: This laptop has no ethernet or CD drive, and only has USB1.1 of which I only have an external floppy that works with it. Also, this computer doesn't have an operating system, and only 256MB of RAM, which Lubuntu runs fine on (live anyway).

I used RMPREPUSB because Netbootin doesn't detect my IDE laptop drive, and even tried booting the LiveCD from a DOS floppy.

Comment: @Takkat I just need to be able to install Lubuntu on to a hard drive that has no other means of installation BESIDES the hard drive itself (USB, CD, Net, none of those are available on this system). I have already tried as I said: I've installed a LiveCD onto the HDD and it runs fine, but when I try to install to the same drive, no matter the partition, it errors out. This was tried on several HDD's so it isn't the drive. and I can't find any other ways to do it.

Comment: As to the errors I get, its mostly about not being able to unmount the drive to install, or it being in use. Mind you I created a root, boot, and swap partition, tried using free space, etc.

Answer (score 1):

Installating to a **different** partition than the boot-partition, or to an unpartitioned space should be possible without issue. Make sure the partition to install is not mounted.

Nevertheless, and because you seem to be unable to use additional partitions on this hard drive, think of plugging the drive into another computer, where you have access to the Internet for installation. For safety reasons unplug any other hard drives on this computer.

This will not only let you install Lubuntu smoothly, but it will additionally give you the advantage of installing all updates, additional applications, or drivers you may need.

After all is setup you can then plug the drive back in to your laptop.

Related questions:

- [How to install Ubuntu without a CD and a USB?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/157598/how-to-install-ubuntu-without-a-cd-and-a-usb)
- [Can I install Ubuntu on the same hard drive I booted with?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/191499/can-i-install-ubuntu-on-the-same-hard-drive-i-booted-with)