# It is possible to install Lubuntu with an other computer using LAN cable?

Tags: system-installation

I got a compaq evo n400c computer and it has no BIOS support for the bootable USB flash drives and there is no CD/DVD ROM! So i want to install the Lubuntu 12.04 with the netboot installer, but i have no idea how it works? I never did like that before so anybody please explain me how it happens? I found some advices on UbuntuDocumentations but it was for Ubuntu or ubuntu minimal and there was a lot of codes.... a bit complicated.

The Server Computer has Ubuntu 12.04.1 (2.54Ghz,650GB HDD, 4GB RAM) The target Computer: (850Mhz, 20GB HDD, 512MB RAM)

Comment: And *why* is that you can't do what the Ubuntu Documentation says? do you get stuck somewhere..? it has lots of "codes" because that's what you have to do there's no way around it.

Comment: Because i don't wanna install the Ubuntu minimal. I need Lubuntu. And i tried the codes with sudo (root power) but the terminal says often: bash no such a file or directory! Actually is it possible to boot an iso file with the network???

Comment: You can perfectly install Lubuntu after you install ubuntu-minimal, [Clean Install of Ubuntu Server over the network](http://askubuntu.com/questions/8539/clean-install-of-ubuntu-server-over-the-network)

Comment: Ubuntu minimal is not really a minimal installation; it is pretty complete. The difference is that the installer is minimal and so can be transferred over PXE.

Comment: okay, i tried to configure my system but i don't understand things. Is there any more specific advice to do this? So my HDD in client PC has a deleted Win95 so it boots up and asking me for a floppy drive. Any possibility to install ubuntu from that DOS terminal?